# Using two fields to control display format on map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, display

I have a point shapefile with several numeric fields, among them FuelFlow and Slope. I have successfully applied colour to the various points according to the value of the FuelFlow field. Now I would like to control some other attribute of the map symbols (shape? size?) according to the value in the Slope field. Something like slope between 0 and 10 gets one display style, 10-20 gets a second style, 20-30 etc.

I get the sense that this is possible in QGIS (using v 2.2.0 - Windows) according to some of the tools in the Style dialog, but I don't know where to start.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I *believe* I saw one online posting about using a CASE statement in the style definition, but now 1) I can't find it in the UI and 2) I don't know how to construct the CASE statement.

Answer (score 3):

I presume you want to achieve something like this:

[image]

You only need to define some rules, like bellow:

[image]

For the same results, you can use CASE statements, if you really want this:

[image]

This is my attribute table:

[image]

and the layer label:

[image]

---

If you want to specify the symbol and its color with data define values specified in the attribute's table, then your attribute's table may look like this:

[image]

Then, in the `Rule properties`, for each label, you need to choose `SVG marker`and to specify which fields stores the the `SVG path` and the symbol `Color`:

[image]

And here's the new result:

[image]

Comment: Close, but not quite. I want to independently define the symbology for two attributes. Using your example, I want to have the actual symbol (airplane, star, penta) linked to the content of the loc_field, and the colour of the symbol linked to the value in the slope field.  Make sense?
Newbie on this forum - how are you adding the screen shots? And I probably did not put this reply in the correct place; am I supposed to use the "answer your question" button?

Comment: To add an image, you can use the 6th buton (counting from the left), when editing a question or an answer. (This isn't possible for a comment)

Comment: @user23742 I've updated my response, to fulfil your requirements.

Comment: I finally found how to use the graduated colours associated with one field plus a second field to control the size of the map symbol. Thanks for your help.